# Emacs hashtags (#tagsLikeThisOne) autocompletion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, hashtag

I hashtag notes that I take with Emacs while I read books, articles, etc - humanities, mostly. I would like to know if Emacs can automatically build a list of hashtags that I enter (in a separate file, probably)? Also, can Emacs - reading from this hypothetical list - offer an incremental (or tab) autocompletion when I start to type the hashtag. I need this feature in order to have a consistent tagging.

Thanx!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html

Comment: Thnx. Actually, I use org-mode. The problem is that it can parse/search for tags only in the agenda files. I tried to designate the whole folder as an Agenda folder. The problem is that I have hundreds of files. If all are to be searched through for the tags, Agenda could take from 5 to 10 minutes to compile results. And that is not acceptable from the point of view of my workflow. On the contrary, Grep gives me un answer instantly.

Comment: @DarkoDraskovici I'm very interested in implementing the same. I wonder how do you perform a search on a specific #hashtag so that you can quickly get a collection of materials that had been tagged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) to generate the TAGS file. For instance, if your notes are in Org mode, you can do this:

```
(require 'org-ctags)
(setq org-ctags-path-to-ctags "/path/to/ctags")

;; Regular expression for the hashtags.
;; Nnote that this would remove the existing definition and effectively disable 
;; the standard use of org-ctags which is to tag <<links>>. If you want to preserve old
;; behavior you need to combine the two regexes.
(setq org-ctags-tag-regexp "/(#[^+]+)/\\1/d,definition/")

(org-ctags-create-tags "directory")
```

Now you can use `org-ctags-find-tag-interactive` to search the tags which claims to have autocompletion:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
      (define-key org-mode-map "\C-co" 'org-ctags-find-tag-interactive)))
```

but I prefer Helm completion, so I just do `M-x helm-etags-select`. You can also ignore the `org-ctags` and build the TAGS yourself:

```
 ctags --langdef=orgmode --langmap=orgmode:.org
       --regex-orgmode="/(#[^+]+)/\1/d,definition/"
       -f /your/path/TAGS -e -R /your/path/*.org
```

(or create a convenience emacs function that does that for you).

Comment: Thank you. This could be a really good solution. Up to the point and light one. The only problem that I can see is that your ctags version does not allow for automatic update of the taglist file. Could you please propose some solution for auto-update: when I add a tag that does not exist, I would like it to be added in the tagfile. Otherwise, I would like the autocompletion behaviour.

Comment: I think the re-building of the TAGS file on demand is implemented by org-ctags really well. Please see `M-x customize-variable` `org-ctags-open-link-functions` to fine-tune the behavior you would like.

Comment: How do I make org-mode use the generated tag file without org-ctags? Can I make it use multiple tag files?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative: You can *bookmark* such notes. And if you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) then you can [tag bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc21).

You can use as many tags as you like for a bookmark, and the tags can be any strings (they can even have associated Lisp values). Bookmarks (tagged or not) are not visible in the bookmarked text, by default. But (with Bookmark+) you can have them be highlighted in various ways.

Comment: Thnx. It seems to be exactly what I need. I will give it a try.